# Fetch unique elements from Array of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, list

I have a Array of String array i want to fetch the unique elements from that array ignoring the case. how can i fetch 
Example:

List of array:

```
[
       ["java,C,Node,ReactJs"]
        ["c","Spring"]
        ["undefined"]
        ["asdja"]
        ["Java","Spring"]
        ["adjasjh"]
        ["adjasjh"]
        ["java"] 
]
```

ExpectedList:

```
[java,C,node,reactjs,spring,..]
```

Comment: Not sure how that input plus those instructions gives you that output, but this is def one you should be figuring out yourself, at least conceptually. Spell out how you imagine you'd achieve this in pseudocode, and ask for help with specific methods - you'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: So, this isn't an array of strings.  This is a bunch of arrays of strings.  Please show the actual starting data format.  Is it an array of arrays of strings?  Or, 7 separate arrays of strings?  What are you actually starting with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array, change [to lower case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by comma, convert into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the unique words, and then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) back to an array:

```js
const arr = [["java,NO,C,Node,ReactJs"],["c","Spring"],["undefined"],["asdja"],["Java","Spring"],["adjasjh", "Spring-roll"],["adjasjh"],["java", "javascript", "java-script"]];

const result = [...new Set(arr.join().toLowerCase().split(','))];

console.log(result);
```

**Older answer - won't work in all cases:**

You can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array of arrays, and use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with [negative lookahead RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/29lHAb/8) to get unique strings:

```js
const arr = [["java,NO,C,Node,ReactJs"],["c","Spring"],["undefined"],["asdja"],["Java","Spring"],["adjasjh", "Spring-roll"],["adjasjh"],["java", "javascript", "java-script"]];

const result = arr.join()
  .match(/([^,]+\b)(?!.+\1[,|$])/ig);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is actually pretty smart. +1

Comment: pretty smart but it fails when one string is contained into another: e.g. `["java", 'javascript']` outputs `javascript` only (or a comma into a word but less likely)

Comment: eh man.. this fixes only some cases (and breaks others).. `['java', 'script', 'java-script']` outputs only `java-script`.. sorry

Comment: @Francesco - the boundary was to strict. Updated to `[,|$]`. Any other test cases?

Comment: @OriDrori yes, try `"java", "script", "java-script", "git"`

Comment: @OriDrori sorry, I really liked your approach. If you wanna give it one more try I would be happy

Comment: @Francesco - I did to. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in all cases. Thanks for finding the caveats :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `map` methods to iterate array and words and also `Set` to return array of unique elements in the end.

```js
const array = [["java,C,Node,ReactJs"], ["c","Spring"], ["undefined"], ["asdja"], ["Java","Spring"], ["adjasjh"], ["adjasjh"], ["java"] ]

const result = [...new Set(array.reduce((r, e) => {
  return r.concat(...e.map(s => s.split(',').map(w => w.toLowerCase())))
}, []))]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could flat the data and use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for keeping the first unique value without mutating it.

```js
const flat = (r, a) => Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(flat, r) : r.concat(a.split(','));

var data = [["java,C,Node,ReactJs"], ["c", "Spring"], ["undefined"], ["asdja"], ["Java", "Spring"], ["adjasjh"], ["adjasjh"], ["java"]],
    unique = Array.from(data
        .reduce(flat, [])
        .reduce((m, v) => ((l => m.has(l) || m.set(l, v))(v.toLowerCase()), m), new Map)
        .values()
    );

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your array, convert every value to lowercase, use `Set` to remove duplicates, and `Array.from` to convert it back to an array.

If your `["java,C,Node,ReactJs"]` is actually: `["java","C","Node","ReactJs"]` you can do it this way:

```js
const array = [
       ["java","C","Node","ReactJs"],
       ["c","Spring"],
       ["undefined"],
       ["asdja"],
       ["Java","Spring"],
       ["adjasjh"],
       ["adjasjh"],
       ["java"] 
];


const unique = Array.from(
  new Set([].concat.apply([], array).map(item => item.toLowerCase()))
  //       ^^^ flatten array     
);

console.log(unique);
```